# Syntax for conditional logic in PostgreSQL check constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (`every_user`) that is acting as a supertable (inheritance). It can have one of two child tables: `populated_user` or `verified_user`. This is generally how I've gone about inheritance in the past. However, in this case there is another table `complete_user` that is both a 'populated' user and a 'verified' one. Which means I have to change up the logic in the top-level table (`every_user`) to accommodate the possibility of a user being *both* 'populated' and 'verified'.

Absent the diamond inheritance, I used something along these lines to ensure that two child records don't share the same parent record:

```
CREATE TABLE every_user (
    ...
    verified_user_id UUID NULL REFERENCES verified_user(id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
    populated_user_id UUID NULL REFERENCES populated_user(id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CHECK(
        (
            (CASE WHEN verified_user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
            (CASE WHEN populated_user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        ) 
        == 1 
    )
)
```

With the diamond inheritance, I've come up with this to ensure that two child records only share the same parent record if they happen to represent a 'complete' user:

```
CREATE TABLE every_user (
    ...
    verified_user_id UUID NULL REFERENCES verified_user(id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
    populated_user_id UUID NULL REFERENCES populated_user(id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
    complete_user_id UUID NULL REFERENCES complete_user(id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CHECK(
        CASE WHEN complete_user_id IS NULL THEN (
            (
                (CASE WHEN verified_user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
                (CASE WHEN populated_user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            ) 
            == 1 
        ) ELSE (
            (
                (CASE WHEN verified_user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
                (CASE WHEN populated_user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            ) 
            == 2
        )
        END
    )
)
```

But I'm not certain that code in the check constraint will evaluate to one of the two boolean expressions based on whether the value of `complete_user_id` column is null or not. Before, the top level code construct was the boolean expression itself, so there was no ambiguity regarding what the check constraint would evaluate to. But here, I'm unsure of whether the syntax is correct for the top level code construct (the `CASE WHEN complete_user_id IS NULL THEN` and `ELSE` blocks). Is it? Will it result in only permitting inheritance by multiple records if the `complete_user_id` column is not null?

Answer (score 0):

Why those bloaty `CASE` expressions instead of simple Boolean operations?

```
complete_user_id IS NULL
AND (verified_user IS NULL
     AND populated_user_id IS NOT NULL
      OR populated_user_id IS NULL
         AND verified_user IS NOT NULL)
 OR complete_user_id = verified_user
    AND complete_user_id = populated_user_id
```

Comment: Because boolean operations don't scale well with new subtables. With the `CASE` expressions — in a typical one-to-one inheritance relationship — you only have to add a single new `CASE` expression for the new subtable column (one line). But with your approach, you'd have to  edit each existing boolean expression to include the new column and then add a new expression to account for the case when the record represents the super of a record of the new subtable.

Comment: But also this doesn't answer the question. I am still wondering if the syntax of the code within the new `CHECK` constraint is correct.

Comment: @shoe: For mere syntax checks, just execute the code. If the syntax is wrong, the system will tell you.